# retrieving IPV6 route flags programmatically?

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming, linux-kernel, ipv6

Is there a way to obtain flags of the IPV6 routing table through any API in `Linux`?

1. `Netlink socket` doesn't show any place for flags.
2. After checking `route` command's source code in `net-tools` it seems that it reads route from `proc` filesystem, i am wary of doing this, as it seems to be OS flavor dependent.

Comment: Netlink sockets are also not cross platform.

Comment: Only looking for various flavors of Linux. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

`/proc` is a and emplementation of [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) for **Linux** originally introduced in 1992. Every effort is made to maintain compatibility with applications using the filesystem. Including for alternative operating systems such as **FreeBSD** that provides a `linprocfs` filesystem to maintain binary compatibility with **Linux** applications.

The same software for `net-tools` is used on all major **Linux** systems, so there should be no issues with using those `/proc` files for system information.